# Taking divergence of the gradient of a scalar field that depends only on the position vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, gradient-flows

The scalar field $f$ depends only on $r=|\underline{\mathbf{r}}|$ which is the position vector in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and I need to calculate the quantity, $$\nabla \cdot \nabla f$$
i went about calculating $\nabla f$ and I got this,

$$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial z})$$
$$ = (f'\frac{x}{r},f'\frac{y}{r},f'\frac{z}{r})$$
$$= f' \frac{\underline{r}}{r} \quad (*) $$
where $f'=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ and i got the $\frac{x}{r}$ from differentiating the position vector.

I'm fairly certain that's okay but my problem comes with taking the divergence so i have that,
$$\nabla \cdot \nabla f = (\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\frac{\partial }{\partial y},\frac{\partial }{\partial z})\cdot\frac{1}{r}(f'x,f'y,f'z)$$
i pull out the $\frac{1}{r}$ from the dot product and use the chain rule.$$\frac{1}{r}(\frac{\partial (f'x)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial (f'y)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial (f'z)}{\partial z}) $$
which when using the chain rule gives
$$\frac{1}{r}(3f'+x\frac{\partial f'}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f'}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f'}{\partial z})$$
Now heres where im unsure i say this is equivalent to,
$$\frac{1}{r}(3f'+\underline{r}\cdot (\nabla f'))$$
we use $(*)$ to get $$\frac{1}{r}(3f'+\underline{r}\cdot(f''\frac{\underline{r}}{r}))$$
$$= \frac{1}{r}(3f'+(\underline{r}\cdot\underline{r})(f''\frac{1}{r}))$$
using the fact that $x \cdot x = |x|^2$ i find that $$\nabla \cdot \nabla f =3\frac{f'}{r}+f''$$

This is my first time really using differential operators in this way so any help checking is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i pull out the $1/r$ from the dot product  ...

That is not allowed! $r = r(x, y, z)$, so you can't just ignore. You have

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \nabla f(r) &=& \nabla \cdot \left(f' \frac{{\bf r}}{r} \right) \\
&=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{xf'}{r} \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{y f'}{r} \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{z f'}{r} \right) \\
&=& \left(\frac{f'}{r} + \frac{x f''}{r}\frac{x}{r} - \frac{x^2f'}{r^3}\right)
 + \left(\frac{f'}{r} + \frac{y f''}{r}\frac{y}{r} - \frac{y^2f'}{r^3}\right) + \left(\frac{f'}{r} + \frac{z f''}{r}\frac{z}{r} - \frac{z^2f'}{r^3}\right) \\
&=& \frac{3f'}{r} + \frac{f''}{r^2}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - \frac{f'}{r^3}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \\
&=& 3\frac{f'}{r} + r^2\frac{f''}{r^2} - r^2\frac{f'}{r^3} \\
&=& 2\frac{f'}{r} + f''
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks that makes alot of sense i was really iffy about that part cause of r being the position vector but i figured it was scalar so i was all good but i see why you cant anyway thank you!!!

Comment: @Questlove Happy to help

Comment: @Questlove There's a neat result in $\mathbb{R}^n$: If $f = f(r)$ then 

$$
\nabla^2 f = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}r}\left(r^{n-1}f' \right)
$$

that's how I saw you had a problem :)